# Use S3 server-side encryption with customer provided key in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, encryption, amazon-s3

I'm interested in using [encrypted S3 buckets with customer provided keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html).

Is there a way to access that kind of bucket from Hadoop ?
From what I see in the various docs or JIRAs, I can't see a way to specify the key.